# Video-React: handleStateChange gets called multiple times when it should be called only once

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-lifecycle, video-reactjs

I am using [Video-React](https://video-react.js.org/components/player/) to implement video playing functionality in my project:

```
 <Player
            ref={(player) => {
              this.state.player = player;
            }}
            src={videoURL}
          ></Player>
```

I am tracking state change this way:

```
 componentDidUpdate(prevProps, prevState) {
    if (this.state.player) {
      this.state.player.subscribeToStateChange(
        this.handleStateChange.bind(this)
      );
    }
  }
 
 
  handleStateChange(state, prevState) {
    const userHasJustPlayedVideo = prevState.paused && !state.paused;
    const userHasJustPausedVideo = !prevState.paused && state.paused;

   
    if (userHasJustPlayedVideo) {
      console.group("userHasJustPlayedVideo: PREVIOUS STATE");
      console.log("previous state: ", prevState);
      console.groupEnd();

      console.group("userHasJustPlayedVideo: CURRENT STATE");
      console.log("state: ", state);
      console.groupEnd();
   
    }

    if (userHasJustPausedVideo) {
      console.group("userHasJustPausedVideo: PREVIOUS STATE");
      console.log("previous state: ", prevState);
      console.groupEnd();

      console.group("userHasJustPausedVideo: CURRENT STATE");
      console.log("state: ", state);

      console.groupEnd();
    }
  }
```

**PROBLEM: `handleStateChange` gets called multiple times when I pause/play video and it follows this pattern.**
In other words, the state property `paused` transitions from true to false or from false to true, and for that **ONE STATE TRANSITITON**, `handleStateChange` gets called **MORE THAN ONCE** and incrementally (See comment below).

```
  // After I play and pause the 1st time

  // userHasJustPlayedVideo block gets logged 1 time
  // userHasJustPausedVideo block gets logged 2 times

  // After I play and pause the 2nd time
  // userHasJustPlayedVideo block gets logged 2 times
  // userHasJustPausedVideo block gets logged 3 times

  // After I play and pause the 3rd time
  // userHasJustPlayedVideo block gets logged 3 times
  // userHasJustPausedVideo block gets logged 4 times

  // And so on and so forth
  // Everytime there's an extra log
  // It seems that handleChange gets called one extra time
  // Everytime I play and pause
  // Which doesn't make sense
```

I need to execute some logic **ONLY ONCE** here:

```
  if (userHasJustPausedVideo) {
      // LOGIC TO BE EXECUTED ONCE
    }
```

But, with the current implementation that logic will get execute **multiple times**.

Any idea what I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm guessing that everytime the state updates, you subscribe to state change again. So you are seeing that pattern of behavior.

You are supposed to subscribe to state change in `componentDidMount` not on `componentDidUpdate`, so it only registers once.

Check out the `subscribeToStateChange(listener)` in methods section of the [docs](https://video-react.js.org/components/player/)

Comment: I tried with componentDidMount but I get this problem: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65448697/video-react-unable-to-subscribe-to-player-state-because-player-is-undefined

Comment: If it has to be done `componentDidUpdate` use another state like `isSubscribed` and check that before subscribing. Like `if (this.state.player && !this.state.isSubscribed)`